# R data.table .SD unexpected behaviour

Tags: r, data.table

I was trying to calculate some basic statistics of a data table and I've come to this (for me) unexpected behaviour.
If I calculate using  everything using "explicit" indexes everything works as expected as in the following example:

```
library(data.table)
n <- 100; reps <- 6; n1 <- 2
df <-  as.data.frame(cbind(matrix(seq_len(n*n1), ncol=n1),
      matrix(sample(0:1000, n*reps, replace=TRUE), ncol=reps)))
dt <- data.table(df)

dtmean <- dt[, lapply(.SD[,c(seq(2,5))], mean, na.rm=TRUE), by=c("V1")]
```

but if I use

```
a=2
b=5

dtmean <- dt[, lapply(.SD[,c(seq(a,b))], mean, na.rm=TRUE), by=c("V1")]
```

the results is not what I expect (previous lines)

Is this intentionally how data.table should work?

so the first part of code for n=10 gives

```
   V1  V3  V4  V5  V6
 1:  1 504 399 430 564
 2:  2 547 294 274 700
 3:  3 555 305 781 326
 4:  4 144 840 983 221
 5:  5 894 659 169  38
 6:  6 788 289 598 433
 7:  7 810 378  86  22
 8:  8 848 212 701 565
 9:  9 412 707 890 160
10: 10  82 580 927 607
```

while the second

```
    V1 V1 V2 V3 V4
 1:  1  2  3  4  5
 2:  2  2  3  4  5
 3:  3  2  3  4  5
 4:  4  2  3  4  5
 5:  5  2  3  4  5
 6:  6  2  3  4  5
 7:  7  2  3  4  5
 8:  8  2  3  4  5
 9:  9  2  3  4  5
10: 10  2  3  4  5
```

shouldn't they give me same results?
the function mean here does not calculate anything since V1 has all different values, the question is about selecting of the indexes, I don't understand why they work in different ways.

Comment: What exactly are you taking `mean` of? From your output it seems you are just selecting columns. `dt[, c(1, 3:6)]`

Comment: please see the edited question

Comment: `dt[, lapply(.SD[,seq(a,b),with=FALSE], mean, na.rm=TRUE), by=c("V1")]` *works*. I'm *guessing* that `data.table` thinks `a` and `b` should represent variables inside the `.SD` environment, so preventing that behavior *within `.SD`* is the key. I don't know if it is truly intentional that `seq(2,5)` works and `seq(a,b)` does not, but the `with=` definitely side-steps the issue here.

Comment: BTW, `dt[, lapply(.SD[,a:b], mean, na.rm=TRUE), by=c("V1")]` also works (`a:b`, no `with=`). I think it's definitely a corner-case of NSE within `data.table`. I don't know if it's a bug, I'm hoping one of the `data.table` devs can inform the discussion. (If not, it might do well to bring this up as an [issue](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/).)

Answer (score 5):

You should use `.SDcols` to control what's included in `.SD` in this case:

```
dtmean <- dt[, lapply(.SD, mean, na.rm=TRUE), by="V1", .SDcols=seq(a,b)]
```

To do it your style, you should use `with=FALSE` on the inner `.SD` call:

```
dtmean <- dt[, lapply(.SD[, seq(a,b), with=FALSE], mean, na.rm=TRUE), by=c("V1")]
```

`.SD` is itself a `data.table`, so `[` has the same semantics, i.e., the issue is the same as the difference between

```
dt[ , seq(a,b)]
```

and

```
dt[ , seq(a,b), with=FALSE]
```

---

Addendum to note that `.SDcols` can also be used to determine `a`,`b` inline in some cases, e.g. if `a:b` is just the numeric columns of the table, we can use:

```
dt[ , lapply(.SD, mean, na.rm=TRUE), by=V1, .SDcols=is.numeric]
```

Or if `a:b` have a pattern in their name, e.g.:

```
dt[ , lapply(.SD, mean, na.rm=TRUE), by=V1, .SDcols=patterns("ends_with_x$")]
```